# Why sound hardware appears as not installed?

Tags: windows, macos, boot-camp

I installed Windows 10 on a late 2011 MacBook Pro using Bootcamp. Now it says that there's no audio hardware installed and there is no sound.

I tried to reinstall drivers using a different Bootcamp package but it says to upgrade to Bootcamp 3.1 first. I tried installing different drivers, but that didn't work either. I'm at the end of my rope here.

What's the link to Bootcamp package where the audio drivers will work? What steps should I take to install it so it will work?

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 needs Boot Camp 6 & a newer Mac than you have. There are no Win 10 drivers for that machine.

Source: [Apple KB - Use Windows 10 on your Mac with Boot Camp](https://support.apple.com/HT204990) &
[Mac computers that support Windows 10](https://support.apple.com/HT204990#models)